# How to compare file content after putting/getting content?

Tags: php, file, compare

I have a content by getting from website

```
$content = file_get_contents( 'https://example.com' );
```

Content has a lot of lines and \n symbols

Then I put content

`file_put_content( 'my-file-path.txt', $content )`;

**And then - contents are not the same after getting or putting content to file**

```
$saved_content = file_get_contents( 'my-file-path.txt' );
```

**Expexted:**

```
$saved_content === $content
```

But this condition is false.

And `sha1($saved_content) !== sha1($content)`

Why `$saved_content === $content` is `false` but strings are equal by content?

**How to compare $content and $saved_content?**

Comment: Use `var_dump` and look at what the content is. Maybe UTF8 characters are being converted to ASCII? Are you observing an issue with `\n` characters?

Comment: Content with `var_dump` the same.

Comment: String count and data type?